# MiniZinc Geocode not printing all solutions to CSP with "all" solutions enabled

Tags: minizinc, optimathsat

**The Issue**

With `solve minimize` I only get one solution, even though there are multiple optimal solutions. I have enabled printout of multiple solutions in the solver configurations. The other optimal solutions are found with `solve satisfy`, along with non-optimal solutions.

**Possible causes**

Could it be that the cardinality function `card()` ranks by enum value where size of two sets are equal? In other words that `card(A, B) > card(B, C)`? If so, do I have to switch the representation of my vertices?

**The Program**

I am creating a MiniZinc program for finding the minimum vertex cover of a given graph. The graph in this example is this:

[image: Example graph]

With Minimal Vertex Cover solutions being:
`[{A, B, C, E}, {A, B, E, F}, {A, C, D, E}, {B, C, D, E}, {B, C, D, F}, {B, D, E, F}]`. **My code only outputs `{A, B, C, E}`.**

Data file:

```
VERTEX = {A, B, C, D, E, F};
       
edges = [|1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
         |1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0
         |0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0
         |0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0
         |0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1
         |0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1|];
```

Solver program:

```
% Vertices in graph
enum VERTEX;

% Edges between vertices
array[VERTEX, int] of int: edges;

int: num_edges = (length(edges) div card(VERTEX));

% Set of vertices to find
var set of VERTEX: span;

% Number of vertices connected to edge resulting from span
array[1..num_edges] of var 0..num_edges: conn;

% All edges must be connected with at least one vertex from span
constraint forall(i in 1..num_edges)
           (conn[i] >= 1);

% The number of connections to each edge is the number of vertices 
% in span with a connection to that edge
constraint forall(i in 1..num_edges)
           (conn[i] = sum([edges[vert,i]| vert in span]));
           
% Minimize the number of vertices in span
solve minimize card(span);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`solve minimize` only show one optimal solution (in some cases, intermediate values might also be shown).

If you want all optimal solutions you must use `solve satisfy` **and** add the constraint with the optimal value:

```
constraint card(span) = 4;
```

Then the model outputs all the 6 optimal solutions:

```
card(cpan): 4
span: {A, B, C, E}
conn: [2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
----------
card(cpan): 4
span: {B, C, D, F}
conn: [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]
----------
card(cpan): 4
span: {A, C, D, E}
conn: [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1]
----------
card(cpan): 4
span: {B, C, D, E}
conn: [1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1]
----------
card(cpan): 4
span: {A, B, E, F}
conn: [2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2]
----------
card(cpan): 4
span: {B, D, E, F}
conn: [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2]
----------
==========
```

Note: I added the `output` section to show all the values:

```
output [
   "card(cpan): \(card(span))\n",
   "span: \(span)\n",
   "conn: \(conn)"
];
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up. I am aiming to use this code on a number of examples - would it be possible to dynamically set the `constraint card(span)` to the lowest found number?

Comment: @Matsern Sorry, but no, you have to first run `minimize` and then add the constraint. I suggest that you run this with a wrapper program which do these steps.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution is to use [**OptiMathSAT (v. 1.6.3)**](http://optimathsat.disi.unitn.it/index.html).

When asking for **all solutions** in optimization mode, the solver returns all solutions *(with respect to the output variables)* with the same optimal value.

**Example:**

```
~$ mzn2fzn test.mzn test.dzn                                        # your instance
~$ optimathsat -input=fzn -opt.fzn.all_solutions=True < test.fzn 
% allsat model
span = {2, 4, 5, 6};
conn = array1d(1..9, [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2]);
----------
% allsat model
span = {1, 3, 4, 5};
conn = array1d(1..9, [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1]);
----------
% allsat model
span = {1, 2, 3, 5};
conn = array1d(1..9, [2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]);
----------
% allsat model
span = {1, 2, 5, 6};
conn = array1d(1..9, [2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2]);
----------
% allsat model
span = {2, 3, 4, 5};
conn = array1d(1..9, [1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1]);
----------
% allsat model
span = {2, 3, 4, 6};
conn = array1d(1..9, [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]);
----------
=========
```

The main advantage wrt. the approach presented in the accepted answer is that OptiMathSAT is **incremental**, meaning that the tool searches for other solutions without being restarted, so that it can re-use any useful information that has been previously generated to speed-up the search (e.g. theory lemmas). *[CAVEAT: this may not be relevant for small instances; also, other MiniZinc solvers may still be faster depending on the input problem]*

**Note:** please notice that `OptiMathSAT` does not print the *labels* of each `VERTEX`, because the `mzn2fzn` compiler removes these labels when compiling the file. However, the mapping among numbers and labels should be obvious.

---

**Disclosure:** I am one of the developers of this tool.